# grails joinTable with legacy database

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a one-to-many table mapping that I want to do with grails. I have a legacy database where I can't change the table structure. I have everything set up, but the only thing I can't figure out is how to get grails to notice the existing foreign keys instead of creating it's own column. I have something like this (simplified):

```
class Customer {
    String listID
    String name
    String address
    // more fields etc.

    static hasMany [notes : Note]

    static mapping = {
        table name:"customers"
        id name:"listID",generator:"assigned"

        // doesn't work, creates a foreign key column in customer_notes table
        // with key: customer_id. I want it to just use the existing column
        // CustomerListID, which has the correct foreign key
        notes joinTable:[name:"customer_notes",key:"CustomerListID"]            
    }
}

class Note {
    String noteID
    String customerListID

    static mapping = {
        table name:"customer_notes"
        id name:"NoteID",generator:"assigned"
     }
}
```

As a side note, I see that joinTable in the grails document says "column" is the inverse column, and "key" is the foreign key. The examples in the docs aren't helpful. I have "Grails in Action" and it says it's going to provide a one-to-many example, then shows a many to many example, and either way it doesn't seem to be a complete example (half the model is missing)!

Any ideas? I have this legacy database, and I'm going to use it read-only. I just want the O/R mapper to hook things together nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Your joinTable in the Customer domain object should use column, not key:

```
notes joinTable:[name:"CustomerNotes",column:"CustomerListID"]
```

Also, the name: should be the name of the join table, not the name of the Note table.

Comment: I had a typo in my question (as you pointed out my model was incorect. It still doesn't work as now stated. I don't understand your last part, about 'the name: should be the name of the join table'. Isn't customer_notes the join table?

Comment: I'm a little confused with your domain model. My understanding of your domain, you need three tables: customers, customer_notes and a third join table. You don't need a domain object for your domain table.

Comment: do you mean I don't need a domain object for my join table? It turns out, that there is no third table. The primary key in customer notes is NoteID, and it has a foreign key CustomerListID. So probably you mean I don't need a column CustomerListID in customer_notes, because that's the one grails will automatically create. That's fine if that's the case. But the problem is, no matter what I do grails creates customer_id as the foreign key column.

Comment: From your description of the tables, you do not have a join table. You just need to specify the name of the foreign key. Replace the joinTable line with: notes: column:customer_list_id.